# how to pass json value to dynatree jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynatree

I am using dynatree jquery for listing values in tree structure.  Here I pass the values(parent,child) like JSON from server side to ajax function I don't know how to place the values in dynatree

How can I place JSON values in my dynatree?

```
Jsonvalue={
"databasename": [
   { "tableName":"employeedetails" , "columnName":"empid" },
   { "tableName":"employeedetails" , "columnName":"empname" },
   { "tableName":"employeedetails" , "columnName":"empsalary" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tree").dynatree({
    initAjax: {
    url: "/serverurl",
    […]
});
```

You need to use initAjax option which will take a url. The url you give should return a json. Dynatree will parse the json and create the tree structure automatically

Please see the [documentation](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html) for more details